# (Non)density of the set of rational functions in the set of meromorphic ones

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

> Let *R* (resp. *M*) be the set of rational (resp. meromorphic) functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. What can we say about the relation among *R* and *M*? 
>   E.g. is *R* nowhere dense in *M* (w.r.t. some reasonable topology on *M*)?

**Motivation:**

It is well known that on a real interval we have Weierstrass approximation theorem meaning basically that the set of polynomials on the interval is dense in the set of continuous functions (w.r.t. the supremum norm). As far as I understand, this can't be generalized in an obvious way to the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ (and even to the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$), and I wonder what *can* be proved in this case.

Any references are most appreciated, as googling didn't quite help. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R$ is dense in $M$ in the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets, i.e. given compact set $K$, $\epsilon > 0$, and $f \in M$, there is $g \in R$ that has $|g - f| < \epsilon$ on $K$ (and in particular the poles of $f$ in $K$ are also poles of $g$, with the same principal parts).  You can get this from Runge's theorem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the function space and topology being used here? Due to poles, neither R nor M are subsets of the space of C-valued functions on C (or even the unit disk). So is the appropriate topology here the compact-open topology on functions from C to the Riemann sphere (with R and M appropriately extended)? Or is there another topology one can give M itself?